# What is the relation between ASLR and the mshta.exe's error "The system cannot execute the specified program"?

Tags: windows, operating-system, reverse-engineering, hta, aslr

I am having a problem running `mshta.exe`. As you can see in the picture below, I get the error: `The system cannot execute the specified program.`

I've created a `test.hta` file and it can't be executed as well. I've tried these solutions and none of them worked:

1. I've disabled App Locker
2. I've disabled the Anti-virus
3. I've turned off windows firewall.

Yet, when I enabled the `ASLR` it worked!
I've edited the registry value `MoveImages` to 1. It's under the key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINESYSTEMCurrentControlSetControlSession ManagerMemory Management`. I've disabled the ASLR before because sometimes I debug DLLs.

My question is: Why did this work? How can the ASLR help with this problem?

[image: test hta file]

Comment: Are you rebooting after changing the ASLR setting?

Comment: Not sure that image helps, what was the command you tried to run, the full command?

Comment: @Anders
Yep I did reboot.

Comment: @user692942
Yeah, I tried the full command and it didn't work as well.

Comment: I'm asking what was the full command, the image does not help show what you run?

Comment: @user692942
the full command: `mshta.exe %TEST_FILE_PATH%`.

I've posted an answer from one of my friends. I think it's very convincing!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A friend of mine has one interesting answer I want to share:

"Its error from within the kernel of `NtCreateUserProcess`, in this api, there're calls to `ZwMapViewOfSection` to map executable image to memory. In our case the MapView returns `STATUS_CONFLICTING_ADDRESSES`.
If you read the  `ZwMapViewOfSection` docs, you will see that Windows cache some address range, so that if an image without ASLR requesting address within the cache, it fails at `ZwMapViewOfSection`.
This wont happen with ASLR because Windows will guarantee the new image base address wont be inside any cache range".